# Having issues fixing "ImportError: cannot import name message_decoder" python nfcpy ndef

Tags: python

Having issues fixing this error "ImportError: cannot import name message_decoder" after installing these two python packages:
nfcpy & ndef.

Answer (score 2):

You may have installed the ndef package https://pypi.org/project/ndef/ but nfcpy depends on ndeflib https://pypi.org/project/ndeflib/. Uninstalling the ndef package should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Locate this File

> projectname\venv\lib\site-packages\nfc\tag_*init*_.py

, go to line 24

**CHANGE**

```
from ndef import message_decoder, message_encoder
```

**TO**

```
from ndef.message import message_decoder, message_encoder
```